# What are the limits of Ajax updateable region in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

*Background: I am reading "ASP.Net MVC 3 Framework..." by Steven Sanderson, and Adam Freeman.*

Let's say you have

```
<div id="ajax_update">
  ...
</div>
```

And this part should be updated via Ajax call. My question is what are the limits/requirements you can put there if you don't consider manually processing some XML/JSON data and you rely on `ResultView` as the output.

In the book I mentioned, there is single entry:

```
@Html.Action(...);
```

So when Ajax method is triggered, this `Html.Action` is then called to get the data to display. But what if I would build that region from two partial views, like this:

```
<div id="ajax_update">
  @Html.Action("List1");
  @Html.Action("List2");
</div>
```

What if I would like to build it from three partial views, what if the actions are from different controllers, what if... -- so in short, what are the limits of the Ajax updateable region? Can's, and cannot's?

Or maybe it is pretty direct -- does it have to be single action (in updateable region) matching exactly the action Ajax calls?

*Once again, I am asking in context of processing data from `ResultView's`, not manually processing JSON data.*

---

For those who prefer concrete example -- you have a music list -- there is action/view for it -- and list of tags (which works as filter) -- also action/view for it. Each click on tag, should update music list and tag list -- so updateable region contains data from two views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering my own question...*

The initial content of Ajax updateable region is whatever you want, Ajax here is completely irrelevant.

The Ajax call is another story -- entire region is wiped out, and then the result from single action call is put instead. The initial content and the outcome of Ajax call does not have to be related in anyway. For example -- at first you can show picture of the sea **AND** picture of the beach, and on each Ajax call you can display the current temperature **INSTEAD** of both pictures (assuming your latter action/view renders temperature, not temperature+pictures).

To keep the example I gave myself in the question -- updating music list and tag list -- the view with music list and tag list has to be created in one Ajax action call.